How to aggregate data using Date with JPA
I'm quite lost. I tried to aggregate data using this entity
@Entity
@Table(
    name = "page_view",
    indexes = [
        Index(name = "idx_page_view_site_date", columnList = "site_id,viewed_at"),
        Index(name = "idx_page_view_session", columnList = "session_id"),
        Index(name = "idx_page_view_url", columnList = "url")
    ]
)
data class PageView(
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    val id: String? = null,

    val sessionId: String,
    val url: String,
    val viewedAt: LocalDateTime,
)

The repository
    @Query(
        """
        SELECT new com.eventuallycoding.blogiq.repository.DailyViewStats(
            CAST(pv.viewedAt as date),
            COUNT(pv.id) ,
            COUNT(DISTINCT pv.sessionId) 
        )
        FROM PageView pv
        WHERE pv.site = :site
        AND (:url IS NULL OR pv.url = :url)
        AND pv.viewedAt BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate
        GROUP BY CAST(pv.viewedAt as date)
        ORDER BY CAST(pv.viewedAt as date) ASC
    """
    )
    fun findDailyViewStatsBySiteAndInterval(
        @Param("site") site: Site,
        @Param("startDate") startDate: LocalDateTime,
        @Param("endDate") endDate: LocalDateTime,
        @Param("url") url: String? = null
    ): List<DailyViewStats>

and the data class for DailyViewStats
data class DailyViewStats(
    val date: LocalDate,
    val viewCount: Long,
    val uniqueVisitors: Long
) {
    constructor(sqlDate: java.sql.Date, viewCount: Long, uniqueVisitors: Long) :
            this(sqlDate.toLocalDate(), viewCount, uniqueVisitors)
}

I have a "group by CAST(pv.viewedAt as date)"
I expect every values grouped by date, eg all the values for 2024-11-01 for instance
However, when I log the result
        val views = pageViewRepository.findDailyViewStatsBySiteAndInterval(site, startDate, endDate, null)


        views.forEach { stat ->
            println("Date: ${stat.date}, Views: ${stat.viewCount}, Unique: ${stat.uniqueVisitors}")
        }
    

I have a strange result, with many records on the same date, even if it's grouped by date
Date: 2024-10-31, Views: 1, Unique: 1
Date: 2024-10-31, Views: 1, Unique: 1
Date: 2024-11-01, Views: 1, Unique: 1
Date: 2024-11-01, Views: 1, Unique: 1
Date: 2024-11-01, Views: 1, Unique: 1

So I'm really lost. I don't understand why the group by function is not working as I am expecting

What is the underlying database? Can you run the equivalent query with SQL on it to validate this results?

It's on SqlLite
And this is a good question. It seems the result of "CAST(pv.viewed_at as date)" is not a date but a timestamp
I must have misunderstood something

SQLite doesn't have a date type. What does .schema page_view (on the sqlite3 command line) say?

intellij give me this DDL
create table main.page_view
(
id                  varchar(255) not null
primary key,
active_time_on_page bigint,
...
viewed_at           timestamp,
...
);

SQLite doesn't have a date type. It uses the concept of type affinity to determine what type a column should have, but essentially any column can have any type at any particular time. When you (or the IDE) created the table with the column viewed_at as 'date', what it actually did was to give it the affinity 'numeric' (section 3.1, part 5). However, what the column actually contains might be a number such as a Unix epoch, or an ISO-8601 datetime, or any of the other supported formats. You should do a select viewed_at from... on the command line to check the format the column has, and then modify your query accordingly. Instead of CAST(x AS date) you should use the date function: date(x) if x is text, or date(x, 'unixepoch') if x is numeric.

You're right and indeed I've succeeded to make it work with this query
SELECT 
    date(viewed_at/1000, 'unixepoch') as day,
    sum(count(id)) as total_views,
    sum(count(distinct session_id)) as unique_sessions
FROM page_view 
GROUP BY date(viewed_at/1000, 'unixepoch')
ORDER BY day;

However my initial question was about making it works with JPA. And apparently it's not possible without a native query (which is defeating the purpose of JPA to me)
